# How do I get data from JSON to use in PrimeNG line Chart?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, observable, primeng

I'm trying to load data from my API into a PrimeNG chart and haven't had any luck. Currently what I've been trying to do is subscribing to my services that gets the data from my API.

What I thought I could do is subscribe to that data from my component, reformat it and push it to a local variable array.

The problem I'm running into is that the data seems to be nesting itself once I call the array from outside the observable.

The Data coming from my API formatted like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "sr_count": 117,
            "month_name": "October",
            "month_num": 10,
            "year": 2017
        },
        {
            "sr_count": 34,
            "month_name": "September",
            "month_num": 9,
            "year": 2017
        }
    ]
}
```

My service to gets the data

```
export class ReportService {
  private reportUrl: string = environment.reportUrl;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  /**
   * Get all SRs
   */
  getSR(groupBy: string, beginDate:string, endDate:string): Observable<Report[]> {

    return this.http.get(`${this.reportUrl}/SR?group_by="${groupBy}"&begin_date="${beginDate}"&end_date="${endDate}"`)
      .map(res => res.json().data)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

My component

```
ngOnInit(){
.
.
.


        let newData = [];
        let dataSet1= [];
        let labels = [];
        this.reportService.getSR('Month', lastMonth, today)
        .subscribe(data => {
            dataSet1.push(data.map(a => a.sr_count))

            let monthName = data.map(item => {
                return item.month_name
            })
            labels.push.apply(labels, monthName)
            console.log(labels) //["October", "September"]
        });


        console.log(labels) // I think its [["October", "September"]]
        console.log(newData) // [[109,34]]

        this.data = {
            labels: labels, //undefined
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'First Dataset',
                    data: dataSet1, //undefined
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: '#4bc0c0'
                }

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This could also be a misunderstanding on my part. i'm assuming the array is being nested outside of the variable becuase this is what it looks like in chrome's console
[image]

Any help getting me on the right path would be so appreciated! I've tried, concatenating, push.apply, and even lodash to try and flatten the array. all three of those give me the results of `[]`.

I've also tried placing `this.data` inside of my observable. When that happens, I can't access data from the primeNG code `<p-chart type="line" [data]="data"></p-chart>` I would also think doing it that way would get hairy if trying to use multiple API calls to load datasets.

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured this one out. Sharing the answer in case anyone runs into this one.

The correct way to get the data from my observable into the `this.data` is

```
        this.reportService.getSR('Day', lastMonth, today)
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.data.datasets[0].data = data.map(a =>  a.sr_count);
        this.data.labels = data.map(a =>  a.day_name);
        this.chart.refresh();

    });
```